# Which power means are constructible?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction, means

The three classic [Pythagorean means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means) $A$, $G$, $H$ (arithmetic, geometric, and harmonic mean respectively) of positive real $a$ and $b$ have a cute geometric construction, as does the quadratic mean $Q$:

[image: pythagorean means]

From this picture the ordering of these power means is directly visible.

What I'm curious about is whether there are other examples of such constructible power means (i.e. $M_q=\left(\frac{a^q+b^q}{2}\right)^{1/q}$). Obviously not all means will work; for instance, it will not be constructible if it can map two constructible numbers to an unconstructible number. The question is which ones *are* possible, and how they would be explicitly constructed.

Comment: $n$-th roots are not constructible unless $n$ is a power of $2$. All integer powers are constructible so the constructible ones are $M_{2^k}$

Comment: @DarthGeek: Makes sense. Do you know how one would construct $M_{2^k}$ in the spirit of the above diagram? I imagine it gets tedious quickly, but a standard algorithm for such seems plausible.

Comment: @DarthGeek I think you want $M_{\pm 2^{k}}$, because $M_{-1}=H$ above...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's right!
I don't know if those means can be easily found as in the diagram, but they can be constructed using the construction of a the sum of two segmenta, the product of two segments and the square root of a segment the old fashion way...

Comment: i guess using (a variant of) [Gauss method](http://www.bioinfo.org.cn/~wangchao/maa/heptadecagon.pdf)

Comment: @DarthGeek Is that fact about constructability of $n$-th roots applicable to real $n$ or just to integer $n$?  For example, the statement seems to ignore values like $n=1/3$.  If it only resolves the question for integral $n$, then more is needed to answer the original question for all real $q$.

Comment: @Matt Any integer power is constructible but only $2^k$-th roots are constructible. Therefore, you can only construct means of the form $M_{\pm 2^k}$

Comment: @DarthGeek: Yes, that's what you said before, but the question is how complete that answer is. The result that "only $2^k$-th roots are constructable" is, as I understand it, only applicable to questions about $n$-th roots, with $n \in \mathbb N^+$. (As circumstantial evidence, we do not say "only $2^k$-th roots and $1/k$-th roots are constructable.") And there are many other cases. The power means are defined for all $q\in[-\infty,\infty]$. They are certainly constructable for $q=-\infty$ and $q=\infty$, for example.

Comment: @Matt yes, and by "only" I meant that the power means $M_q$ for $q \neq \pm 2^k$ is not constructible. We could consider $M_{-\infty}$ and $M_\infty$ as $\lim_{k\to\infty} M_{\pm2^k}$ just as $M_{-\infty}$ and $M_\infty$ are defined as $\lim_{q\to\infty} M_{\pm q}$.

Comment: @DarthGeek: Yes, it is very clear (even from the beginning) what you meant. What is not clear is your reasoning for thinking this is a complete answer. You have extended your answer twice now (and it still doesn't include the geometric mean) -- using a clear line of reasoning would help to avoid these problems, as well as help convince someone who doesn't just believe whatever they hear.

Comment: @DarthGeek: Can you convert that into a (possibly partial) answer?

Comment: @Semiclassical sure. I'll get to it!

Comment: For many of the products, quotients and square roots, having a reference unit is required. If only $a$ and $b$ are given, I don't know how to create any more power means than the ones showed by your picture.

Comment: @DarthGeek: A reference unit should not be required, since all the means are scale-invariant: $M_q(c\cdot a,c\cdot b)=c\cdot M_q(a,b)$. Or, in other words, you can use whatever you want as the reference unit; the final answer will not be affected by your choice.

Comment: @Semiclassical, what's the source of this nice diagram, yours? The classical civilizations knew 10+ distinct means, as discussed  here: http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/tast.2009.0006#.U_VjeIBdVRY. Are all described by line segments in a semicircle?

Comment: @alancalvitti: Alas, no---it's from Wikipedia. (I should edit the question to link to that.) And I'm not versed in the remainder of the Pythagorean means, so I can't weigh in there; given the Greek use of geometry instead of algebra, though, it seems quite likely.

Comment: @DarthGeek: FYI, the grace period on the bounty has started. So if you're still interested in giving an answer, now is the time to do it...

Answer (score 1):

For an algebraic number over $\mathbb Q$, in order to be constructable it's minimal polynomial should be of a degree $2^n$ , thus $M_{2^n}$

Answer (score 1):

This is a construction for $M_4$:
[image: construction]

$AC=a$ and $AK=b$.

Using a dummy unit length $(AB)$ you construct $GH=a^4$ and $NO=b^4$ ([example for $a^2$ construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580985/construction-of-line-segment-of-a-length-a2/1580988#1580988)).

Let $BQ=a^4+b^4$, $R$ is the middle point for $BQ$ so $BR=(a^4+b^4)/2$.

Using the same dummy unit we construct the square root $BT$ of $BR$ and the square root $BW$ of $BU=BT$.

We now have your desired mean. The dummy unit is uninfluent, if you change the lenght of $AB$ the length of $BW$ does not change.